# Solve system of large number coupled ODEs as an array using solve_ivp

Tags: python, arrays, scipy, ode, differential-equations

I would like to solve coupled differential equations using SciPy solve_ivp function in Python. I can do it for 2 or 3 equations, like in the code below:

```
def sol_fun():
    def dndt(t,V):
        
        GTotUp = GUp + np.sum(GUpM*V[0:2]) #GUpM is a vector of size 2
        GTotDown = GDown+np.sum(GDownM*(V[0:2]+1)) #GDownM is a vector of size 2
        n1=V[0]
        n2=V[1]
        p=V[2]

        n_dot = -kappa*n1 + N*GDownM[0]*(n1+1)*p - N*GUpM[0] * n1*(1-p)
        n_dot2 = -kappa*n2 + N*GDownM[1]*(n2+1)*p - N*GUpM[1] * n2*(1-p)
        pdot = GTotUp*(1-p)-GTotDown*p

        return [n_dot,n_dot2, pdot]

    sol = solve_ivp(dndt, [t[0], t[-1]], [0,0,0], method='LSODA', t_eval=t)
    return sol
```

As you can see, the equations are coupled, because in every time step I need to calculate GTotUp, which is summing over V[0:2], namely, n1 and n2. And I explicitly write out each variable name.

Now I would like to generalize this problem to N equations (K equations for n_dot and (N-K) equations for pdot), but I can not just write out each variable N times, like below, because I can have hundreds of these equations:

```
def sol_fun():
    def dndt(t,V):
        
        GTotUp = GUp + np.sum(GUpM*V[0:K]) #GUpM is a vector of size K
        GTotDown = GDown+np.sum(GDownM*(V[0:K]+1)) #GDownM is a vector of size K

        # Define all the variables
        n1=V[0]
        n2=V[1]
        ...
        nK=V[K]
        p1=V[K+1]
        ...
        pN=V[N]

        # Define differential equation for each variable
        n_dot = ...
        n_dot2 = ...
        ...
        n_dotK = ...
        pdot1 =...
        ...
        pdotN=...
```

How I could implement all these variables in a single array (vector)?

I tried something like this below, but it did not really work:

```
def sol_fun():
def dndt(t,V):

        ################ When I write this definition below, it gives me an error.
        n=V[0:K] # here I define n as a vector entries for vector V from entry 0 to K
        p=V[K:N] # define p as the next entries from K to N
        ###################
    
        GTotUp = GUp + np.sum(GUpM*V[0:K]) #GUpM is a vector of size K
        GTotDown = GDown+np.sum(GDownM*(V[0:K]+1)) #GDownM is a vector of size K
    
        pm=np.sum(p) #pm is a number
    
        ndot=-kappa*n + rho*GDownM*(n + 1)*pm - rho*GUpM*n*(1-pm) 
        pdot = GTotUp*(1-p) - GTotDown*p
    
        return [ndot, pdot]
```

It gives me a following error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (2,) + inhomogeneous part.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look at the error line (don't expect us to guess where it happens!).

Comment: I'm making a guess that there's a problem with the return value of the function.  `solve_ivp` wants an float numeric array that matches the initial conditions in shape.  Your working case returns `[n_dot,n_dot2, pdot]` which matches the [0,0,0].  What is `[ndot, pdot]`?  2 numbers matching [0,0]?  When using `scipy` functions like this, follow the docs exactly.

Comment: @hpaulj [ndot, pdot] are variables which implicitly assume N equations: K equations for ndot and (N-K) equations for pdot. My original question is how to solve N equations without explicitly writing the names of each variable, but rather using arrays (like in the code block 2)

Comment: Try returning `np.array([ndot, pdot], dtype=float)`.  That's what `solve_ivp` is trying to do for you.  If it doesn't work for you, it won't work for `solve_ivp`.  From the docs **fun must return array_like with shape (n,)**.  No "implicit" structures are recognized.

Comment: @hpaulj No, that is not enough to get a flat array, it is the conversion of the current return value into an ndarray that produces the error. Use array concatenation, `return np.concatenate([ndot,pdot])`.

Comment: @LutzLehmann, I don't expect it to work.  It will produce an error, probably the same.  I wanted to focus the OP's attention on what his function returns.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks, it is exactly what was needed, to concatenate. If wanted to write out explicitly, it would read: return [ndot[0], ndot[1], ..., ndot[K], fdot].